# Draw 3D Plot for Gensim model

Tags: python-3.x, pca, gensim

I have trained my model using Gensim. I draw a 2D plot using PCA but it is not clear too much. I wanna change it to 3D  with capable of zooming .my result is so dense.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from matplotlib import pyplot
X=model[model.wv.vocab]
pca=PCA(n_components=2)
result=pca.fit_transform(X)
pyplot.scatter(result[:,0],result[:,1])
word=list(model.wv.most_similar('eden_lake'))
for i, word in enumerate(words):
  pyplot.annotate(word, xy=(result[i, 0], result[i, 1]))
pyplot.show()
```

And the result:
[image]

it possible to do that?

Comment: Please add your actual code to the question rather than adding an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function uses t-SNE instead of PCA for dimension reduction, but will generate a plot in two, three or both two and three dimensions (using subplots). Furthermore, it will color the topics for you so it's easier to distinguish them. Adding `%matplotlib notebook` to the start of a Jupyter notebook environment from [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) will allow a 3d plot to be rotated and a 2d plot to be zoomed (don't do both versions at the same time with `%matplotlib notebook`).

The function is very long, with most of the code being for plot formatting, but produces a professional output.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import seaborn as sns

from gensim.models import LdaModel
from gensim import corpora
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
# %matplotlib notebook # if in Jupyter for rotating and zooming
```

```py
def LDA_tSNE_topics_vis(dimension='both',
                        corpus=None, 
                        num_topics=10,
                        remove_3d_outliers=False,
                        save_png=False):
    """
    Returns the outputs of an LDA model plotted using t-SNE (t-distributed Stochastic Neighbor Embedding)

    Note: t-SNE reduces the dimensionality of a space such that similar points will be closer and dissimilar points farther

    Parameters
    ----------
        dimension : str (default=both)
            The dimension that t-SNE should reduce the data to for visualization
            Options: 2d, 3d, and both (a plot with two subplots)

        corpus : list, list of lists
            The tokenized and cleaned text corpus over which analysis should be done

        num_topics : int (default=10)
            The number of categories for LDA based approaches

        remove_3d_outliers : bool (default=False)
            Whether to remove outliers from a 3d plot

        save_png : bool (default=False)
            Whether to save the figure as a png

    Returns
    -------
        A t-SNE lower dimensional representation of an LDA model's topics and their constituent members
    """
    dirichlet_dict = corpora.Dictionary(corpus)
    bow_corpus = [dirichlet_dict.doc2bow(text) for text in corpus]

    dirichlet_model = LdaModel(corpus=bow_corpus,
                               id2word=dirichlet_dict,
                               num_topics=num_topics,
                               update_every=1,
                               chunksize=len(bow_corpus),
                               passes=10,
                               alpha='auto',
                               random_state=42) # set for testing

    df_topic_coherences = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['topic_{}'.format(i) for i in range(num_topics)])

    for i in range(len(bow_corpus)):
        df_topic_coherences.loc[i] = [0] * num_topics
        
        output = dirichlet_model.__getitem__(bow=bow_corpus[i], eps=0)
    
        for j in range(len(output)):
            topic_num = output[j][0]
            coherence = output[j][1]
            df_topic_coherences.iloc[i, topic_num] = coherence

    for i in range(num_topics):
        df_topic_coherences.iloc[:, i] = df_topic_coherences.iloc[:, i].astype('float64', copy=False)

    df_topic_coherences['main_topic'] = df_topic_coherences.iloc[:, :num_topics].idxmax(axis=1)

    if num_topics > 10:
        # cubehelix better for more than 10 colors
        colors = sns.color_palette("cubehelix", num_topics)
    else:
        # The default sns color palette
        colors = sns.color_palette('deep', num_topics)

    tsne_2 = None
    tsne_3 = None
    if dimension == 'both':
        tsne_2 = TSNE(n_components=2, perplexity=40, n_iter=300)
        tsne_3 = TSNE(n_components=3, perplexity=40, n_iter=300)
    elif dimension == '2d':
        tsne_2 = TSNE(n_components=2, perplexity=40, n_iter=300)
    elif dimension == '3d':
        tsne_3 = TSNE(n_components=3, perplexity=40, n_iter=300)
    else:
        ValueError("An invalid value has been passed to the 'dimension' argument - choose from 2d, 3d, or both.")

    if tsne_2 is not None:
        tsne_results_2 = tsne_2.fit_transform(df_topic_coherences.iloc[:, :num_topics])
        
        df_tsne_2 = pd.DataFrame()
        df_tsne_2['tsne-2d-d1'] = tsne_results_2[:,0]
        df_tsne_2['tsne-2d-d2'] = tsne_results_2[:,1]
        df_tsne_2['main_topic'] = df_topic_coherences.iloc[:, num_topics]
        df_tsne_2['color'] = [colors[int(t.split('_')[1])] for t in df_tsne_2['main_topic']]

        df_tsne_2['topic_num'] = [int(i.split('_')[1]) for i in df_tsne_2['main_topic']]
        df_tsne_2 = df_tsne_2.sort_values(['topic_num'], ascending = True).drop('topic_num', axis=1)
    
    if tsne_3 is not None:
        colors = [c for c in sns.color_palette()]

        tsne_results_3 = tsne_3.fit_transform(df_topic_coherences.iloc[:, :num_topics])
        
        df_tsne_3 = pd.DataFrame()
        df_tsne_3['tsne-3d-d1'] = tsne_results_3[:,0]
        df_tsne_3['tsne-3d-d2'] = tsne_results_3[:,1]
        df_tsne_3['tsne-3d-d3'] = tsne_results_3[:,2]
        df_tsne_3['main_topic'] = df_topic_coherences.iloc[:, num_topics]
        df_tsne_3['color'] = [colors[int(t.split('_')[1])] for t in df_tsne_3['main_topic']]

        df_tsne_3['topic_num'] = [int(i.split('_')[1]) for i in df_tsne_3['main_topic']]
        df_tsne_3 = df_tsne_3.sort_values(['topic_num'], ascending = True).drop('topic_num', axis=1)

        if remove_3d_outliers:
            # Remove those rows with values that are more than three standard deviations from the column mean
            for col in ['tsne-3d-d1', 'tsne-3d-d2', 'tsne-3d-d3']:
                df_tsne_3 = df_tsne_3[np.abs(df_tsne_3[col] - df_tsne_3[col].mean()) <= (3 * df_tsne_3[col].std())]

    if tsne_2 is not None and tsne_3 is not None:
        fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, # pylint: disable=unused-variable
                                       figsize=(20,10))
        ax1.axis('off')

    else:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(20,10))

    if tsne_2 is not None and tsne_3 is not None:
        # Plot tsne_2, with tsne_3 being added later
        ax1 = sns.scatterplot(data=df_tsne_2, x="tsne-2d-d1", y="tsne-2d-d2",
                              hue=df_topic_coherences.iloc[:, num_topics], alpha=0.3)
        
        light_grey_tup = (242/256, 242/256, 242/256)
        ax1.set_facecolor(light_grey_tup)
        ax1.axes.set_title('t-SNE 2-Dimensional Representation', fontsize=25)
        ax1.set_xlabel('tsne-d1', fontsize=20)
        ax1.set_ylabel('tsne-d2', fontsize=20)

        handles, labels = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
        legend_order = list(np.argsort([i.split('_')[1] for i in labels]))
        ax1.legend([handles[i] for i in legend_order], [labels[i] for i in legend_order], 
                   facecolor=light_grey_tup)

    elif tsne_2 is not None:
        # Plot just tsne_2
        ax = sns.scatterplot(data=df_tsne_2, x="tsne-2d-d1", y="tsne-2d-d2",
                             hue=df_topic_coherences.iloc[:, num_topics], alpha=0.3)

        ax.set_facecolor(light_grey_tup)
        ax.axes.set_title('t-SNE 2-Dimensional Representation', fontsize=25)
        ax.set_xlabel('tsne-d1', fontsize=20)
        ax.set_ylabel('tsne-d2', fontsize=20)

        handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
        legend_order = list(np.argsort([i.split('_')[1] for i in labels]))
        ax.legend([handles[i] for i in legend_order], [labels[i] for i in legend_order], 
                  facecolor=light_grey_tup)

    if tsne_2 is not None and tsne_3 is not None:
        # tsne_2 has been plotted, so add tsne_3
        ax2 = fig.add_subplot(121, projection='3d')
        ax2.scatter(xs=df_tsne_3['tsne-3d-d1'], 
                    ys=df_tsne_3['tsne-3d-d2'], 
                    zs=df_tsne_3['tsne-3d-d3'],  
                    c=df_tsne_3['color'],
                    alpha=0.3)

        ax2.set_facecolor('white')
        ax2.axes.set_title('t-SNE 3-Dimensional Representation', fontsize=25)
        ax2.set_xlabel('tsne-d1', fontsize=20)
        ax2.set_ylabel('tsne-d2', fontsize=20)
        ax2.set_zlabel('tsne-d3', fontsize=20)

        with plt.rc_context({"lines.markeredgewidth" : 0}):
            # Add handles via blank lines and order their colors to match tsne_2
            proxy_handles = [Line2D([0], [0], linestyle="none", marker='o', markersize=8,
                                    markerfacecolor=colors[i]) for i in legend_order]
            ax2.legend(proxy_handles, ['topic_{}'.format(i) for i in range(num_topics)], 
                       loc='upper left', facecolor=(light_grey_tup))

    elif tsne_3 is not None:
        # Plot just tsne_3
        ax.axis('off')
        ax.set_facecolor('white')
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
        ax.scatter(xs=df_tsne_3['tsne-3d-d1'], 
                   ys=df_tsne_3['tsne-3d-d2'], 
                   zs=df_tsne_3['tsne-3d-d3'],  
                   c=df_tsne_3['color'],
                   alpha=0.3)

        ax.set_facecolor('white')
        ax.axes.set_title('t-SNE 3-Dimensional Representation', fontsize=25)
        ax.set_xlabel('tsne-d1', fontsize=20)
        ax.set_ylabel('tsne-d2', fontsize=20)
        ax.set_zlabel('tsne-d3', fontsize=20)

        with plt.rc_context({"lines.markeredgewidth" : 0}):
            # Add handles via blank lines
            proxy_handles = [Line2D([0], [0], linestyle="none", marker='o', markersize=8,
                                    markerfacecolor=colors[i]) for i in range(len(colors))]
            ax.legend(proxy_handles, ['topic_{}'.format(i) for i in range(num_topics)], 
                      loc='upper left', facecolor=light_grey_tup)

    if save_png:
        plt.savefig('LDA_tSNE_{}.png'.format(time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")), bbox_inches='tight', dpi=500)

    plt.show()
```

An example plot for both 2d and 3d (with outliers removed) representations of a 10 topic [gensim](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim) LDA model on subplots would be:

[image: LDA t-SNE Dimensional Reduction Plots]

Answer (score 1):

It's really interesting, but I think you got wrong in some lines.
The very second 'for' (by j) is:

```
for j in range(num_topics):
    _ ,coherence = output[0][j]
    df_topic_coherences.iloc[i, j] = coherence
```

Now it's correct!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in principle it is possible to do 3D visualization of LDA model results. [Here](https://towardsdatascience.com/visualizing-topic-models-with-scatterpies-and-t-sne-f21f228f7b02) is more information about using T-SNE for that.